# Why each style property must be declared twice when using the Support Library APIs for the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using the v7 support library in order to have an ActionBar on API Level 10+. And I want to customize the look a bit.So I added an application theme.
But the [google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) said :

> Please Note: when overriding attributes for an ActionBar style you must specify each attribute twice: once with the "android:" namespace prefix and once without.
>
> each style property that you declare must be declared twice: once using the platform's style >properties (the android: properties) and once using the style properties included in the Support >Library (the appcompat.R.attr properties—the context for these properties is actually your app).

Why we need declare each style property twice ? Or how does "android:" prefix work?

Comment: I think android itself have some issues with its own, if they told it in developers blog, then I think we must need to go through with it. android: prefix for to identify that we are using some things from android itself, I think. But can you please tell me what you exactly wants to do?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52505/discussion-about-android-properties-issue join this jason

Comment: andorid prefix is for api level 11 (picking from the android framework) and above the other is for below api level 11. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html.

Comment: @Raghunandan has given correct answer

Comment: @Raghunandan  how can android system can pick from the app project(not android framework) when without android prefix ? I don't know how it works.

Comment: @Raghunandan Does android get attributes from my app project when style item's name without 'android' prefix ? e.g. <!-- Support library compatibiwlity --><item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

Comment: @JasonW from the support library(AppCompat) below api level 11 and from the android framework fro api level 11 and above (native). I din't say app project. you misunderstood

Comment: @Raghunandan :) I know this.I've read the google docs. But i want to know how android system achieves this.Any rules?

Comment: @JasonW you will have to dig into the source code which is not required as far as i know. But you can if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

That is reasonable I guess, beacuse this "android:" prefix means to get attributes from system, and if it fails system can get attributes via another declaration without the prefix.
This is a good way to allow you app both catch up with the lasted andorid style and of great compatibility